# Why can't I access localhost without an internet connection?

Tags: localhost, ping

For some reason I cannot access `localhost` without an internet connection in Ubuntu.

As soon as I disconnect from the internet (with the networkmanager GUI), both `ping localhost` and `ping 127.0.0.1` return:

```
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

I switched off iptables, `iptables -L` gives:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target prot opt source destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

target prot opt source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target prot opt source destination
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Run the command:

```
sudo ipmasq
```

Try to ping localhost and hopefully it should work.